# About Laravel 6.0 QueryCache / QueryCacheable

Tags: laravel, caching

When users visit the **post pages**, (mysqld) CPU using will be so high.

Basicly, the post page calls page **content query, comments (of that post), check that comments have any subComments, rating/liking status and counts** etc. Anyway this page loads slowly. Therefore I need to use **QueryCacheable**. It works well. But I have a few questions about it.

```
Rennokki\QueryCache\Traits\QueryCacheable;
```

- Is there any drawbacks of using this cache method for all models? E.g: **If I use this cache for a long time** for comments and/or
  posts, and **let's say members added a new comment for the same post,
  or writer updated the post; It will be clear or somethings will be
  missing/mixed?**
- This method use the default file cache, right? If, it's yes; do you recommend using Redis, Memcache or any others? My performance
  problem is related to MySQL side; it is so high when the posts are
  opened. (Posts, comments, liked, rating of comments)

Using:

```
use Rennokki\QueryCache\Traits\QueryCacheable;
YourModel extends BlaBla
{
    use QueryCacheable;
    protected $cacheFor = 300*12*14; //one week
    ..
}
```

PHP 7.2 and MySQL 5.7.

Thank you.